# Web service getting data from USB devices on Raspberry Pi

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, gpio

I have a question about getting data on the Raspberry Pi. I know that we can create RESTful services to get data from GPIO with the help of RPi.GPIO library. But what if I want to get data from traditional USB devices? Say I have a USB Bluetooth dongle and I can read data through operations in command line. But is it possible to perform the same through a web service? Any possible help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Someone already voted (not me) to close this as "unclear what you're asking".  You really need to be more specific about what you're trying to do.  Otherwise the answer is "yes, you you can redirect command line output through a REST service" and you still won't be any closer to what it is you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. I am not sure what data exactly you want to receive, but.. Since you can read data from your BT device via command-line tool (hcitool maybe), you can write cgi script to interact with it via web page. Here an example code in perl. This code generates html page with output of smartctl program. You can modify it to send certain parameters and parse an output lines right in perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard);

# header lines
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

print "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">\n";
print "<html>\n";
print "<head>\n";
print "  <title>S.M.A.R.T. data</title>\n";
print "</head>\n";
print "<body>\n";

print "S.M.A.R.T. output.\n";

my $cmd="/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/smartctl -d sat -a /dev/sda";
my @list=`$cmd`;
foreach $ln (@list)
{
print "$ln<br>";
}
print "</body>\n";
print "</html>\n";
```

P.S. Code is not perfect, but it works in my RPi.